# Checking request body in Grape API

Tags: grape-api

I have a line like this in my Grape endpoint to check the contents of the POST body, to provide a testing endpoint:

```
return 'OK' if request.body.string == 'TEST'
```

In my development environment on my laptop, this works just fine. In our staging and production environments, however, it throws an exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `string' for #<Unicorn::TeeInput:0x0000000b0d0290>
```

From what I can find this has to do with Rack, but I'm pretty surprised to find different behavior from middleware between two environments. I wondered if anyone out there has run across this and might have a suggestion, because I see that Unicorn::TeeInput doesn't have an easy way to check the contents, seemingly. I'm hoping that perhaps there's an "official" way to directly access the request body in Grape, but I haven't found one yet.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `env['rack.input']`, which should return an input stream (actually a [`Rack::Lint::InputWrapper`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Lint/InputWrapper) or workalike) from which you can read the request body:

```
return 'OK' if env['rack.input'].gets.eql? 'TEST'
```

I've tested this and it works locally using both WEBrick and Unicorn.

Comment: Nice one -- that does work on both, and with my specs as well. What made this worse is that the specs were passing locally and on CircleCI, but then the code broke once deployed. It's unfortunate that request.body doesn't return the same thing across web servers. Thanks for the suggestion!